# How to bundle javascript using Parcel in Electron?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, parceljs

I'm using https://github.com/parro-it/electron-parcel-example to use Parcel with Electron.

My project is https://github.com/patrykkalinowski/dcs-frontlines-electron

I have basic setup where `renderer.js` is served by Parcel correctly:

**renderer.js:**

```
// This file is required by the index.html file and will
// be executed in the renderer process for that window.
// All of the Node.js APIs are available in this process.

require('./app/map')
```

**app/map.js:** (ommited non-relevant code)

```
module.exports = {
    addFeature: function(coords) {
        unitsSource.addFeature(new Feature(new Circle(coords, 1e6)))
    }
}

import { Buffer } from "buffer"; // needed after 'fs' is being transpiled

const fs = require ('fs');

import Map from 'ol/Map.js';
import View from 'ol/View.js';
import Feature from 'ol/Feature.js';
import GeoJSON from 'ol/format/GeoJSON.js';
import Circle from 'ol/geom/Circle.js'
import {Tile as TileLayer, Vector as VectorLayer} from 'ol/layer.js';
import {OSM, Vector as VectorSource} from 'ol/source.js';
import {Circle as CircleStyle, Fill, Stroke, Style, Text} from 'ol/style.js';
```

So far so good, it works. Problem arises when trying to add another file to the mix:

**app/dcs.js:**

```
const mgrs = require('mgrs')
const map = require('./map')

module.exports = {
    receiveData: function(data) {
        data = JSON.parse(data)
        keys = Object.keys(data)

        for (key of keys) {
            var mgrs_string = data[key].mgrs_position.UTMZone + data[key].mgrs_position.MGRSDigraph + data[key].mgrs_position.Easting + data[key].mgrs_position.Northing

            var coords = mgrs.toPoint(mgrs_string)
            map.addFeature(coords)

        }
    }
}

map.addFeature([0,0]) // testing
```

`npm start` results with:

```
App threw an error during load
/Users/patryk/Code/dcs-frontlines-electron/app/map.js:7
import { Buffer } from "buffer"; // needed after 'fs' is being transpiled
       ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:752:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:827:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:677:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:609:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:601:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:715:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:14:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/patryk/Code/dcs-frontlines-electron/app/dcs.js:2:13)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:827:10)
```

This error is caused by `require('./map')` in `dcs.js` file (2nd line)

I think that I need to tell Parcel to include `dcs.js` file in the build, but how to do it?

This is my Parcel code in **main.js:**

```
// Parcel bundler
function runParcel() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    let output = "";
    const parcelProcess = execa("parcel", ["index.html"]);
    const concat = chunk => {
      output += chunk;
      console.log(output);
      if (output.includes("Built in ")) {
        parcelProcess.stdout.removeListener("data", concat);
        console.log(output);
        resolve();
      }
    };
    parcelProcess.stdout.on("data", concat);
  });
}
```

Comment: Which version of node are you using? This looks like an issue with understanding ES6 imports.

Comment: @cmbuckley v10.15.3

Comment: I just upgraded to v10.16.1, nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

Your error is an indication that the invoking javascript code doesn't understand ES Modules import syntax. In your case the invoking code comes from Electron. Your dependencies are like this:

```
main.js ---> ./app/dcs.js ---> ./map.js 

// ./map.js contains ES import
import { Buffer } from "buffer";
```

, starting [here](https://github.com/patrykkalinowski/dcs-frontlines-electron/blob/master/main.js#L78).

And Electron doesn't understand `import` natively. I am not sure, if you can bring Electron to support it by passing node flags via [`--js-flags`](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/chrome-command-line-switches.md#--js-flagsflags). As node supports ES modules e.g. via `--experimental-modules --es-module-specifier-resolution=node` and Electron is based on node.js, maybe that's a thing. But haven't tested that.

A safe alternative is to use Babel to transpile your Electron code first to CommonJS syntax, e.g.:

```
babel <your-electron-files-or-folder> --out-dir ./dist/main
```

.babelrc:

```
{
  ...
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs"]
}
```

Or create a main bundle with `parcel build main.js --target: node`.

Hope, that helps.